# ASP.NET MVC - Pass value between Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I've got 2 views: Question and Answer. From the Question View, Detail Action I wanna redirect to Answer View, Create Action, so I've placed:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.QuestionId.ToString(), "Create", "Answer", "Answer", new { id = Model.QuestionId })
```

and in Answer View:

```
public ActionResult Create(string id)
{
    (...)
    return View();
}
```

But the id in Create(string id) is always null. How can I pass this value properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a wrong [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx) of the ActionLink helper. It should be:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    Model.QuestionId.ToString(),     // linkText
    "Create",                        // actionName
    "Answer",                        // controllerName
    new { id = Model.QuestionId },   // routeValues
    null                             // htmlAttributes
)
```

which would generate

```
<a href="/answer/create/123">123</a>
```

---

whereas you are using:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    Model.QuestionId.ToString(),     // linkText
    "Create",                        // actionName
    "Answer",                        // controllerName
    "Answer",                        // routeValues
    new { id = Model.QuestionId }    // htmlAttributes
)
```

which generates:

```
<a href="/Answer/Create?Length=6" id="123">123</a>
```

I think that now it's not difficult to understand why your anchor doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have chosen wrong `ActionLink` overload. Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.QuestionId.ToString(), "Create", "Answer", new { id = Model.QuestionId }, null)
```